# How does one determine the sign of the charge acquired by a material through rubbing?

Tags: electrostatics, electrons, charge

Suppose that a glass rod is rubbed with silk. Then the glass rod gets positively charged and the silk gets negatively charged. After this, the negatively charged silk is made to touch a pith ball. What kind of charge is acquired by the pith ball?

Comment: using electroscope and common sense.

Answer (score 1):

Because silk is not a very good conductor, the charge Will not flow. But if it did, the ball would get the negative charge since some of the negative charge would flow to it, reducing the magnitude of negative charge of the silk.

Comment: When a rod is rubbed with silk both body get charged now if electrified glass rod is brought ib contact with silk with which it was rubbed the no longer attract each other they also do not attract or repel other light objects as they did on being electrified why ????